# Excel multiple lookup array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that I would like it to select the smallest size picture frame that could be used based on the size values, basically return the smallest frame that would fit the image.

So far I have a vertical array formula that can select the smallest frame that will fit the size requirements but I have one column that I would want to stay static i.e another match that would only give the results from the selection with the same type ID/

My current formula is as follows:

```
= INDEX($A$2:$A$16,MATCH(4,MMULT((I2:L2<=$B$2:$E$16)+0,{1;1;1;1}),0))
```

At the minute i am just referencing the type as another lookup but i would like to have it so it will only attempt to match ones with the corresponding type, currently if the size is larger than availible within the correct type it will select a type that has that size availible.

I’ve tried to show what i mean in the screenshot! I want it to only pick up type 1 but it is selecting type 3 because the mmult is seeing that is the only one that would fit.

[image]

Help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a load of nested if statements to section of the types to make it simpler to code

Thanks anyway peeps!

Answer (score 0):

If the frame sizes to be looked up are in ascending order, you could use something like this

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MIN(IF((($B$2:$B$4>=F2)*($C$2:$C$4>=G2)*($D$2:$D$4>=H2)),ROW($C$2:$C$4)))-1,1)`

based on this sort of data layout

[image]